# List of servers per accounts showing 'No server found' in OPM (Open PostgreSQL Monitoring)?

Tags: postgresql, nagios

I installed OPM[Open PostgreSQL Monitoring] by following instructions mentioned [here](http://opm.readthedocs.io/opm-core/Installation.html)

While accessing the local address , it is showing no servers found [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jarYK.png).

I'd installed postgreSQL and that has different dBs.

Please anyone help me to Solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah I'm using PostgreSQL

Comment: so where you got the problem please describe in detail

Comment: What are the changes are to be made in [check_pgactivity](https://github.com/OPMDG/check_pgactivity/blob/master/check_pgactivity) in order to get Servers ?

Comment: Can you show your `opm.conf` file?

Comment: are configured addresses and ports the same on both systems?